# Synology NAS ssh key auth not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, synology

I follow the directions [here](https://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/01/15/ssh-into-your-synology-diskstation-with-ssh-keys//?from=@) on how to setup ssh key auth on my synology NAS. These are typical linux configurations so nothing special; I include the link for reference.

This gets me

> ssh root@

but what I want is user specific login.

So, I modified /etc/passwd and set the shell to /bin/sh

I can log in as that user but not with key auth. I have checked 4 different websites; all saying indentical things. So, I must just be missing something dumb.

Comment: As always, check the server logs for hints (possibly after increasing the loglevel ...)

Answer (score 0):

By default ssh creates a `.ssh` folder in your root folder where it stores the keys.
So you need your user to have a home directory.

On Synology go to Control Panel > User > User Home. Check the box next to Enable User Home Service & choose a volume that you want your users’ home directories to reside.

Did you see this guide?
https://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/01/16/log-in-to-a-synology-diskstation-using-ssh-keys-as-a-user-other-than-root/